# Solutions to non-linear equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am attempting to solve the following equation
$$(1-|a|^2)(x-b)(1-\bar{b}x)+(1-|b|^2)(x-a)(1-\bar{a}x)=0$$
where $a,b,x\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|a|,|b|,|x|<1$. By inspection, $a=b=x$ is a solution however I am not too sure whether this is the only analytical solution or not. I first have decided to reduce this to considering $a,b,x\in(-1,1)$ to study a more simpler equation where we look at solutions to
$$(1-a^2)(x-b)(1-bx)+(1-b^2)(x-a)(1-ax)=0.$$
Numerically it appears as though the only real solutions occur on the line $a=b$ but I am finding it hard to even show this analytically! Any pointers would be much appreciated in either the real case or the complex case.

Comment: What happens if you construe $a,b$ as fixed (unknown) constants, multiply everything out, and obtain a quadratic equation in $x$, where the coefficients of the equation would be expressions involving the constants $a,b$.  Would anything prevent you from applying the formula for the quadratic equation?

Comment: @user2661923 I did consider this. In the complex case you obtain solutions $$x=\frac{-1+|b|^2|c|^2\pm \sqrt{(|b|^2-1)(|c|^2-1)(b\bar{c}-1)(\bar{b}c-1)}}{\bar{b}(\bar{c}(b+c)-1)-\bar{c}}$$ and I couldn't quite determine whether $b=c=x$ is the only parameters that give equality.

Comment: For the real version of your equation, here is a solution  with $a\neq b$ and all values in $(-1,1)$: $a=\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}$, $b = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}$, $x = \frac{\sqrt{21}}{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values of $a$, $b$, and $x$ in $(-1,1)$, the equation $(1−a^2)(x−b)(1−bx)+(1 − b^2)(x − a)(1 − ax) = 0$  defines a two-dimensional surface. This raises a question about what you mean by 'solving' the equation. Does a rendering of the surface suffice?

[image: Surface defined by equation over the specified range of values]

One way to characterize the solutions algebraically could be as follows. Let $b_0$ and $x_0$ be any values in $(-1,1)$. Then a solution is obtained by $$\left(a = \frac{b_0(1+x_0^2)-2x_0}{b_0(2x_0)-(1+x_0^2)},\quad b = b_0,\quad x = x_0\right).$$

Another way to characterize the solutions might be to select particular values of $x$ and, for each $x$-value, plot a contour in the $a$-$b$ plane.

[image: Contour plots for various values of the x variable]